# Are content.php and content-single.php the same?

Tags: theme-development, the-content, post-formats

I understand that when using `get_template_part('content', get_post_format());` it will help choosing a `post format` for specific page according to post format.

And if there is no post format 'i.e it's standard', then it will fallback to `content.php`

But what if I used `content-single.php` with some logic like this:

```
if (get_post_format() == false) {
    get_template_part('content', 'single');
    } else {
        get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
}
```

Do I still need `content.php` page? is there any other functionalities that I don't know about?

Answer (score 3):

No, `content.php` and `content-single.php` are not the same thing.

In your example CODE:

```
if (get_post_format() == false) {
    get_template_part('content', 'single');
} else {
    get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
}
```

WordPress will load `content-single.php` when `get_post_format()` is `false`. However, [`get_template_part( $slug, $name )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) may still try to load `content.php` when you call it with `get_template_part('content', get_post_format());` in the following example:

1. `get_post_format()` returns (for example) `video`.
2. But you don't have `content-video.php` template part file.

So basically, even when `get_post_format()` is not `false`, `content.php` will still provide you with the default template part if the corresponding post format related template part was not created.

> ***Bottom line:*** whatever the main `$slug` is, it's always a good idea to keep the default template part file as the final fallback template part (in your case `content.php` is that default fallback template part file). **So YES, you may still need it**. So don't delete it, leave it alone.

The following is the part of the CODE from core function `get_template_part`. You'll see that, the core always loads `$templates[] = "{$slug}.php";` as the final fallback template file:

```
function get_template_part( $slug, $name = null ) {
    // ... more CODE from WP core
    $templates = array();
    $name = (string) $name;
    if ( '' !== $name )
        $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";

    $templates[] = "{$slug}.php"; 
    locate_template($templates, true, false);
}
```

Then, in [`locate_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) function it loops through the `$templates` array until it finds the corresponding file, with the following CODE:

```
function locate_template($template_names, $load = false, $require_once = true ) {
    $located = '';
    foreach ( (array) $template_names as $template_name ) {
        if ( !$template_name )
            continue;
        if ( file_exists(STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $template_name)) {
            $located = STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $template_name;
            break;
        } elseif ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template_name) ) {
            $located = TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template_name;
            break;
        } elseif ( file_exists( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name ) ) {
            $located = ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( $load && '' != $located )
        load_template( $located, $require_once );

    return $located;
}
```

So as you can see from the above CODE, if you delete `content.php`, and if the theme user has a post format for which you don't have a template part file, WordPress will not find template file to fall back to, so will simply load nothing in that case. As a final attempt, WordPress tries to load a template part file from `wp-includes/theme-compat/` core directory, but there is no `content.php` template part file in WP core.

> ***Note:*** However, if you are building a child theme and the parent theme already contains the `content.php` file, then you don't need `content.php` file in the child theme (if you don't do any modification there), because in that case, WordPress will use the parent theme's `content.php` file as the fallback template part file.

Answer (score 0):

> You could get by with only the one template (content.php). That's
>   usually less than ideal.

From [the teamtreehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/unclear-about-the-function-of-contentphp-contentpagephp-and-contentnonephp)'s blog should clear your question.

For me that approach is a fallback way.